# What is the most exemplary explanation of the difference between the consensus algorithms in blockchain and IOTA?

Tags: asktheexperts

in brief (if possible) what is the layman explanation of the difference between the different consensus algorithms in blockchain and IOTA?

How would you explain how IOTA is e.g. more efficient compared to PoW or PoS?

Thanks